# Firebase Cloud Messaging Can't register service worker when deploy angularjs app war in tomcat 8.0

Tags: angularjs, firebase, tomcat, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hope you can help me, I'm using **Firebase Cloud Messaging** in my **AngularJs** app in local enviroment all is ok, but when I generate a war with Gradle **(gradle copyTask)** and deploy on **tomcat 8.0** just get:

***"FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration). at http://localhost:8090/test/scripts/vendor.49aa6ce4.js:89:9150"***